# Silverlight - Read Macintosh Resource-Fork

Tags: macos, silverlight-4.0, resources, fork

Is there a way to open and read a Macintosh resource fork through a Silverlight app hosted in a web browser?

I have found several links which hint at appending `@"/rsrc"` to the file name when using mono, however a `FileSecurityState` violation is thrown when that is done using Silverlight.  Obviously the resource fork itself can't simply be opened using the OpenFileDialog and simply appending the `@"/rsrc"` to the file name will give the security violation.

How can I open and read a Macintosh resource fork from Silverlight?

- http://go-mono.com/forums/#nabble-td2267247

(mod - you may want to change the tags on this question to one 'resource-fork' instead of two separate tags.)